# Flutter: Loop through all children of a widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to loop over my widget screen/page and edit my current widget by server results:
i am getting an list of objects like this:

```
{
  "states": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "visible": true,
      "enable": false
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "visible": false,
      "enable": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Each id point of widget that contains KeyValue,
i need to search for wholes keys in my page/screen that match to my server id's than edit current widget with it properties.
i need to do it first time before build function called, so i created `WidgetTree`, that get screen widget as param(child) and loop over it in initState and recreate the new child(screen/page) with all the updates.
then build will call the new child.

My code:

```
class WidgetTree extends StatefulWidget {

  final Widget child;

  const WidgetTree({Key? key,required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WidgetTreeState createState() => _WidgetTreeState();
}

class _WidgetTreeState extends State<WidgetTree> {

  late Widget parent;

  @override
  void initState() {
    parent = widget.child;
    _widgetRecursion(null, parent);
    super.initState();
  }

  _widgetRecursion(Widget? parent,Widget? child){
    if(child == null) return;

    if(child is RegularButton){

      // child = Visibility(child: child,visible: false,); // not working i am losing refrence.
    }

    if(child is Scaffold){
      _widgetRecursion(child,child.body);
    }

    if(child is Container){
      _widgetRecursion(parent,child.child);
    }

    if(child is MultiChildRenderObjectWidget){
      child.children.forEach((subChild)=>_widgetRecursion(child,subChild));
    }

    if(child is SingleChildScrollView){
      _widgetRecursion(child,child.child);
    }
    if(child is SingleChildRenderObjectWidget){
      _widgetRecursion(child,child.child);
    }
    if(child is StreamBuilder){
      // final t = child as StatefulWidget;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return parent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi There. This seems like an over complicated approach to whatever is it that you trying to achieve. Try elaborating what you actual use case is.

Comment: Thanks first of all the quick reply
What are you recommend?
i am really tring to find about it at the web, unfortunately nothing found.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am trying to recreate my tree with some updates before i am displaying it.  my app have full control from the server
(visibility ,enable/disable clicks whole over the app). i am getting from my server list of object with ids and status about visibility and enable/disable. each Id will point to current widget then with it current properties i will change it.

Comment: It is still vague what you are trying.
So you want following:
Get the widget as an argument in function, grab child of that widget,
and wrap with visibility. is it right ?

please show us `_handlePermission` function code too.

Comment: It is very badly explained, please edit your question and be more detailed.

Comment: @manofknowledge you are correct, `_handlePermission` you can ignore from it ,it should be as i edit `_widgetRecursion`  function name.
In addition i will edit question for better explaination.

Comment: Why do you have parent parameter if you are not using parent inside the function in any way.

Comment: And also I think you need to return something from recursion and you are not returning anything.

Comment: @manofknowledge i update my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any code that may modify the existing widget tree. I think it is better to add **Visibility** to every RegularButton (or other widgets you want to control) and then control them by searching the key.
You can do it by controlling all keys somewhere (like [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), [GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) + StatefulWidget, or something else that can [manage the widget statement](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)) and change the widget state directly.

If you try to recursively track down and modify the tree, I can only think of copying a new one. That means you must replica all the widgets you tracked:

```
// original tree is widget.child
...
late Widget newTree;

@override
void initState() {
  newTree = _widgetRecursion(null, widget.child);
  super.initState();
}

Widget _widgetRecursion(Widget? parent,Widget? child) {
  if(child is RegularButton){
      return Visibility(child: child,visible: false,);
  }
  if(child is SomeWidget){
     return SomeWidget(
       someProperty: child.someProperty,
       child: _widgetRecursion(child, child.child),
     );
  }
  if(child is TopWidget){
    return TopWidget(child: _widgetRecursion(child, child.child);
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return newTree;
}
...
```

Comment: and how to deal with FutureBuilder/StreamBuilder?

Comment: I think it depends on the case. If the case is simple,  I don't think there is any problem passing FutureBuilder/StreamBuilder in the same way because they also widgets.